# Is there a way to use parameters in Jenkins job description field?

Tags: jenkins

I have a job creator job that creates other jobs in jenkins and I would like to use the created jobs name in the description.

For example for name "JobXX" i would like to have:
"This is documentation for JobXX etc.."

In "Execute shell" build step I can refer to the jobs name via $JOB_NAME parameter but that does not seem to work in the description field.

Any ideas on how to do this? Or if it's even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Never used it, but take a look to the **Project Description Setter Plugin**:
https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Project+Description+Setter+Plugin

In this blog it explains better how to use it:
http://www.tothenew.com/blog/setting-dynamic-project-description-and-build-description-in-jenkins/

Among the different variables you can use there is {PROJECT_NAME} which fits your needs.

Besides this, this plugin allows you also to automatically set descriptions to each specific build.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Sorry, my first answer in StackOverflow. I added some detail that can help to his specific request (the job/project name).